# Multiple text data-bind in knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have two properties Name , age observable.Is it possible to display the two properties together and apply css for the same?

Is it possible to do a data-bind with both Name and age?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data-bind` attribute can specify an expression like:

```
data-bind="Name() + ' (' + Age() + ')'"
```

Otherwise, you can create a computed observable to represent your value like:

```
viewModel.nameWithAge = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.Name() + ' (' + this.Age() + ')'";
}, vieWModel);
```